# Excel overlapping if cell merged

Tags: excel, overlap

How to make text overlapping when cells is merged?

I trying in cell format align by FILL and Justify, but text still do not overlapping next cell, next cell is blank and do not contains any info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have text from merged cells overlapping into next blank cell.

Normally you shouldn't rely on overlapping at all - **this is just interface feature** to show you more data when possible (i.e. when next cell/cells to the right are blank).

If you need to show more data adjust column width and/or enable text wrapping. Text overlapping was not meant for this.